# What is this circuit's purpose

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design

The input is a current source (photomultiplier), and the output is connected to a charge amplifier (I belive).

I tried to draw the schematics from the circuit board, but I don't know what the three-leg grey components are (transistors I suppose ?) and I am not sure my schematic is right.

I suspect it is a transimpedance amplifier, but I don't understand how it is powered.

[image]

[image]

[Schematics and picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/movWW.jpg)

Comment: It's more polite to embed the pictures in your post, rather than a link to them, that's the 'mountains' icon on the edit bar when you edit your original post.

Comment: @Neil_UK as new user, Aygator might not be able to do that. Anyway, embedded them for him.

Comment: You have to provide the part numbers of the transistors so that we know whether they are NPN or PNP, without that it is impossible to guess at the purpose of the circuit. The P/Ns should be written on the sides of the transistors.

Comment: If those are transistors, they must be PNP, based on the polarity of those electrolytic capacitors. It appears that the transistors have been replaced - the originals had 4-terminals - one of which was likely connected to case.

Comment: In OP's schematic, the 33k resistor is actually 3.3k.

Answer (score 2):

I took some liberties with the layout of your schematic, and I wonder if it's intended to be an inline booster/amplifier which uses "phantom power" coming in through the output pin ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR6RP0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Everything inside the box is your circuit. The rest is 'support' stuff I added to make it behave.
The circuit works even better if Q1 is a N-Channel MOSFET or a P-Channel J-FET - so maybe you could read the part number for us?

[image]

edit: updated after glen_geek's observation that your 33k is actually a 3k3.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense ! The reason why is because this circuit (which I am now sure is a preamp) was connected to an amplifier that I thought was faulty. I had 14 V at the input of the amplifier, thinking that a decoupling capacitor was faulty. Now I believe this was made by design. It is an odd way to power the circuit, but i think it makes sense now. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: If I could abuse your kindness (i am not much of an electronician...) would you know how the NPN transistor behave when they are not powered ? Do they behave like a diode ? (If you do not have time to reply, do not bother, I will do some research on textbooks about NPN transistors).

The reason I am asking is because the circuit have been used with another amplifier (that did not power the output with 14V), and the measurement gave strange results that I would like to be able to explain in hindsight now that I have a better understanding.

Anyway, thanks again for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

guessing thoses transistor should be NPN (due to position & resistor going to ground) I tryied to understand what type of divider it was.

It is apparently a voltage divider by 2 with offset at middle of the source power voltage.

This is a simulation to do again with real references to ensure /confirm that or not

Comment: This circuit layout doesn't look like it gives particularly useful results ... Why would the base of your 'Q3' just have a parallel resistor & capacitor to ground with no bias path?